# A-Frame Animation not starting on event emission

Tags: javascript, animation, aframe

I am trying to animate a plane in A-frame with either the `a-animation` component or the [aframe-animation-component](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation/) after the user clicks on a text box. I want to rotate the plane to a vertical position so that the user falls. The animation works without an event listener, but it fails to fire when I add the `startEvents` or `begin` attributes to the `a-entity` containing the plane. The event called `fallclick` is emitted from a text `a-entity` called `fallSelector` when it is clicked.

Here is a section of my HTML code:

```
<a-entity 
                static-body
                id="plane" 
                rotation="-90 0 0" 
                geometry="primitive: plane; width: 2; height: 2" 
<!--            animation="property: rotation; to: 0 0 0; delay: 500; startEvents: fallclick;" -->
                >
        <a-animation attribute="rotation" to="0 0 0" delay="500" dur="1000" begin="fallclick" ></a-animation>
</a-entity>
```

Here is the the JavaScript event code:

```
fallSelector.addEventListener('click', function () {
            fallSelector.emit('fallclick');
            console.log(fallSelector + ': Emit fallclick');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) for the `<a-animation>` component, you need to emit the event on the animation primitive:

```
<a-animation id="my-animation" begin="foo"></a-animation>
<!-- js: my-animation.emit("foo") --!>
```

2) for the animation component you need to emit the event on the entity containing the animation

```
<a-entity id="bar" animation="startEvents: foo"></a-entity>
<!-- js: bar.emit("foo") --!>
```

live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3f3o49uq/)

Comment: Got it! Thanks, Piotr.

Comment: This no longer works with version 1.0.4. When I try it, I get the error "document.querySelector(...).emit is not a function". Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: @MikeMichaels, the second option should be working (because `a-animation` is no longer supported

Comment: You're right. There was something else wrong with my code. Thanks!